# How use Google Cloud on Source Tree?

Tags: git, google-cloud-storage, atlassian-sourcetree

I just created a new Repo in Google Cloud and wanna use the Source Tree app as controllers for my git interactions.

But I keep been asked this password for push.
[image]

Is no my Google account password I already setup the 2-verification password, but still not able to create this password.

**EDIT:**
If I try to follow this guide [Set Up a Google Cloud Git Repo In SourceTree](https://gist.github.com/dustintheweb/21c308b82a024fc8d585)

It says:

1. https://console.developers.google.com
2. Left panel > source code > releases
3. Click the link "Configure your repository" in the first paragraph
4. In the second sentence, click the little help icon w/ a ?
5. Click the link "generate your git credentials"

On **Step 2** there is no "*source code/releases*" option
[image][image]

And If I try to go on **Step 4** "*Git Credentials*", in credentials only have API Credentials, not Git.
[image]

Comment: You may have to store the passwords in plain text, as indicated in the walk-through published in GitHub: [Set up a Google Cloud Git Repo in SourceTree](https://gist.github.com/dustintheweb/21c308b82a024fc8d585). 
For general information on remote repositories you may read the [Setting Up a Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories) page.

Comment: @George the problem is, this step "left panel > source code > releases" don't have more this options.

Comment: Which options are missing, exactly? 
You may try the following steps: 
-Go to Tools | Options
-Click on the Authentication button 
-Under Saved Passwords, click Edit and change as needed.

Comment: @George I edit my question with a better explanation about this guide. Thanks for the help so far, I hope I can solve this soon XD. Even I did no found this Tools|Options and Authentication Button

Comment: You are right: there is no such menu as one does't have to generate git credentials this way, taking into consideration the specific kind of hosting provided for the repository in this case. You can simply use your Oauth client ID. 
More related detail is to be found on the ["Credentials, access, security, and identity"](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158857?hl=en-GB) documentation page.

Comment: A more intuitive illustration is provided in the developers' console, if you navigate to "API APIs & Services" then you select in the main window the "Cloud Source Repositories API". In "About this API" you can see the "Using credentials with this API" titled paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recomended way (with gcloud credentials)**

<s>I found a workaround to get it work (macOS):</s>

```
cd myproject
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
```

You must be authenticated in your local `gcloud` CLI and have it in your `$PATH`.
Then start SourceTree through the Terminal:

```
open /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/MacOS/SourceTree
```

This will propagate your `$PATH` to SourceTree in order to make the script `git-credentials-gcloud.sh` available.

I managed to find a solution that does not involved the Terminal. You should add the following in the Info.plist of the SourceTree.app package (`/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Info.plist`), at the end of the main `<dict>` item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist .....
<dict>
...
...
    <key>LSEnvironment</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key><string>CONTENT OF YOUR $PATH</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then you need to flush the macOS cache by

- Rename SourceTree.app to SourceTree2.app
- Rename SourceTree2.app to SourceTree.app

You are done, SourceTree should now be able to use the gcloud credentials.

**With password**:

Browse https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform

Comment: This link is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it's easy to do so.
I am on Microsoft Windows 11 OS machine.

Firstly, follow these instructions on creating a repository on Google Cloud (gcloud) Repositories:

1. https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/create-code-repository
2. Clone the remote repository-- on Google Cloud-- to your local machine (the way to do it explained under that tutorial)

Then, install the SourceTree, if you do not have one.

[image]

On SourceTree, navigate to the "Add" option, in order to browse to just cloned repository on your local machine.

And you are ready to go!
You can commit the code on your Google Cloud Repositories.

Best regards